# Xcode unable to find Emoji in scope

Tags: swift

Right now I am trying to make my code so that the emojis i use are usable elsewhere in the file. Im not the best with words so this might not make sense.

The emojis are enumerated as such:

```
    enum Emojis: String {
        case eyes1 = ""
        case eyes2 = ""
        case nose1 = ""
        case nose2 = ""
        case mouth1 = ""
        case mouth2 = ""
        
        static let allValues: [Emojis] = [.eyes1, .eyes2, .nose1, .nose2, .mouth1, .mouth2]
        
        func getImage() -> UIImage {
            let image = UIImage(named: self.rawValue)!
            return image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        }
    }
```

I am trying to use this here:

```
extension Emojis {
    func getImage() -> UIImage {
        let image = UIImage(named: self.rawValue)!
        return image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    }
}
```

Using the extension part, Xcode tells me that Emojis could not be found in scope.

I tried putting the curly braces after just the cases for emojis, but then i got 30 errors around other parts of the code.

I was expecting it to just accept the Emojis values

Comment: `Emojis` already has a `getImage`. Why are you declaring it again?

Comment: Where do you declare the enum, where do you declare the extension? The error complains about scope but we can’t see the scope from the code you have provided

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The Emojis is in the highest level (i think thats what it is called). It can be accessed by anything!

Comment: Unrelated but if the enum conforms to CaseIterable you don’t need allValues since you get an allCases property for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the `named` images in your project,
the following works for me:

```
enum Emojis: String {
    case eyes1 = ""
    case eyes2 = ""
    case nose1 = ""
    case nose2 = ""
    case mouth1 = ""
    case mouth2 = ""
    
    // static let allValues: [Emojis] = [.eyes1, .eyes2, .nose1, .nose2, .mouth1, .mouth2]
    
    //     func getImage() -> UIImage {
    //         let image = UIImage(named: self.rawValue)!
    //         return image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    //     }
}

extension Emojis {
    func getImage() -> UIImage {
        if let image = UIImage(named: self.rawValue) {
            return image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        } else {
            return UIImage()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: Emojis.nose2.getImage())
    }
}
```

Comment: this helped! thanks! I replaced the emoji Strings with the file names.